# Почему JSON.stringify после push возвращает пустой массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему `JSON.stringify` после push возвращает пустой массив?

Как правильно пишется такое выражение?

```js
let data = [];

data['name'] = []; // 'name' - это динамическое название, заранее неизвестен
data['name'].push('Заголовок');

data = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Выше это пример кода.
Нужен json чтобы потом записать в куки через js плагин https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

`Cookies.set('name', data, { expires: 365 });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала вы определяете `data` как массив, но потом присваиваете ему динамические свойства, как объекту. Это возможно, потому что массив является подтипом объекта. Однако JSON при сериализации игнорирует «объектные» свойства массивов, он сохраняет только их индексируемые элементы. Если вы определите `data` как объект, тогда это будет работать, как вы ожидаете:

```js
let data = {};

data['name'] = []; // 'name' - это динамическое название, заранее неизвестен
data['name'].push('Заголовок');

data = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Как то все запутано в js с этими массивами в объектах

Comment: Не без этого) Но если вы посвятите время спокойному изучению базовых вещей, всё станет на свои места)